# VBA ADODB.Recordset values disappear suddenly

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

When loading data from mssql database in a recordset all fields get populated correctly. If I inspect the recordset in vba debugger all fields have values. As soon as I access one field f.e to assign the value to a variable, some of the field values just seem to disappear. When I then check in debugger the same fields have "Empty" as value. Any idea what the issue might be?

```
Sub FillData(query)
    
    On Error GoTo eh

    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Source = query
    Dim cn As Object
    Set cn = GetConnection()
    Dim cnstr As String
    cnstr = GetConnectionString()
    cn.Open cnstr
    
    With rs
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .Open
                        
            If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
            Else
                Do While Not rs.EOF

                   'if i check here in debugger all fields have values 

                article = rs.Fields("ARTICLE")
                lst_nr = rs.Fields("LST_NR")
                desc = rs.Fields("DESC")
                CurrencyCustomer = rs.Fields("CUR_CUST")
                CurrencyPartner = rs.Fields("CUR_PART")
                 
                 'if i check here again, some lost the values. Also not all variables are populated...

                    'processing values

                rs.MoveNext
                        
                Loop
                
            End If
        .Close
    End With
   
cleanUp:
    If Not (rs Is Nothing) Then
        If (rs.State And eState.adStateOpen) = eState.adStateOpen Then
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        End If
    End If
    If Not (cn Is Nothing) Then
        If (cn.State And eState.adStateOpen) = eState.adStateOpen Then
        cn.Close
        Set cn = Nothing
        End If
    End If
    GeneratePdf
    Exit Sub
eh:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    GoTo cleanUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you are assigning variables that were not declared in this procedure. That means we don't know what they are here. Are those form elements or global variables? ALWAYS put `Option Explicit` at the top of EVERY module. This will ensure you never create a variable on accident.

Comment: Thanks for the input with "Option Explicit" this is usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, the ADODB.Recordset does not like it when fields are accessed in a different order when they were populated (SQL-SERVER). At least my recent tests pointed in this direction. As a workaround, i loop through the recordset and fill the fields in dictionarys and store the dictionarys then in a collection. This way a can still access the fields through their name property. As a bonus, I don’t have to keep the connection open as long as I need the recordset and can close it immediately after filling the collection.

```
...
 Dim articles As New Collection
 Dim article As Object

 Do While Not rs.EOF
    Set article = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    
      For Each fld In rs.Fields
        article.Add fld.Name, fld.Value
      Next

    articles.Add article
    rs.MoveNext
 Loop
...
```

Comment: Keeping a Key/Value pair around is a great idea to reduce calls to the DB server. There is no reason to have a Dictionary and a Collection. They are both iEnumerable objects that can be used interchangeably. I prefer Dictionary for it's extra features but if what you need is a collection then just make the collection without making the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things you are doing seem verbose and redundant.

We can shorten the preamble using the `.OpenRecordset` command. The cleanup is also not necessary. Objects that have no references get garbage collected. If we use a `With` block that will ensure our recordset object has no object references when the Sub is complete.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FillData(ByVal query As String)
    On Error GoTo eh

    With CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(query, dbOpenDynaset)
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            Do While Not .EOF

                'if i check here in debugger all fields have values 

                article = .Fields("ARTICLE")
                lst_nr = .Fields("LST_NR")
                desc = .Fields("DESC")
                CurrencyCustomer = .Fields("CUR_CUST")
                CurrencyPartner = .Fields("CUR_PART")
                
                'if i check here again, some lost the values. Also not all variables are populated...
                'processing values
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If

        .Close
    End With

eh:
    If err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description
    End If

    GeneratePdf
End Sub
```

Comment: Will the with block also close the connection?

Comment: Technically, yes, when the object is disposed the `Dispose` procedure will close the connection. I always put `.Close` before `End With` for good measure and to communicate to the reader what we are doing.